# phpmailer recipients failed

Tags: php, phpmailer

So I am just started learning phpmailer and it is very complicated for me. I got this example file and I change some of the coding to match my project(like Database and Email stuff). I got this smtp error that I don't understand why.

This is the error:

`SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: shahirazrie@gmail.com`

`Fatal error: Uncaught phpmailerException: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: shahirazrie@gmail.com in C:\xampp\htdocs\qpms\class.phpmailer.php:754 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\qpms\class.phpmailer.php(576): PHPMailer->SmtpSend('Date: Tue, 7 De...', '--b1_d0be631347...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\qpms\email_reminder_course.php(163): PHPMailer->Send() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\qpms\email_reminder_course.php(76): send_email('shahirazrie@gma...', 'Ban Kar Weng', 'DCP5301', 'DATA STRUCTURE ...', '2110', '', '2021-12-07', '') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\qpms\class.phpmailer.php on line 754`

This is my coding:
https://github.com/shazrie01/remindermail/blob/main/reminder

Comment: If you're just starting to use PHPMailer, you're doing one big thing wrong: you're using a really old and unsupported version, so go and [get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and base your code on the examples provided with it.

Comment: @Synchro do I need to install the whole thing or  just some file

Comment: Since "the whole thing" is "just some files", yes, I guess? The best idea is to read the readme which tells you how to load PHPMailer (composer is good), and which files you need.

Comment: thank you so much @Synchro for your help appreciate it bro